# Normal speed for Samba directory listing

Tags: samba, lan

I have a Linux samba share (server version 4.2) connected by a 100 mbps LAN ethernet. Locally on the server, listing a directory with around thousand entries takes a little less than one second. From the client (FreeBSD) on the mounted samba share this time increases by six. This can't be normal, can it?

```
# smb.conf:
[global]
interfaces = eth0
bind interfaces only = yes
display charset = utf-8
[Intenso Memory Center]
path=/media/intenseo
read only = no
```

No workgroup and server string set. I use `mount_smbfs` (version 2-0.90.2) with the `-I <IP address>` option. But setting a workgroup and server name and mounting with the name does not make it better. Someone suggested using `oplocks = yes` as a share option, tried it, doesn't make a difference.

What can be done about it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're sharing a usb device via samba. I found on my computers that using the internal usb port in combination with the internal ethernet controller leads to a slower data throughput - compared to sending/receiving data to/from a sata drive. (The Raspberry Pi for instance uses the same memory controller for usb and ethernet which explains negative throughput there.)

However, there are tunables for samba which can be played around with, depending on your hardware you might do your own benchmarking to figure out what works best for you. Some example settings are:

```
socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY SO_SNDBUF=131072 SO_RCVBUF=131072
min receivefile size = 128k
oplocks = yes
level2 oplocks = no
max smbd processes = 128
```

Check this [page](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/speed.html) for more information.